# Presto SQL/Hive Sub query or join?

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql, presto

I am working on a query that requires I join with another hive table to pull a username using a user ID number. Is it possible to write a sub-query just for the result of that user name or should I do a Join?

Table 1: Assigned_Tasks has columns for task_number, owner_id, title, description, progress, ds

Table 2: Employee_info has columns for employee_id, employee_name, employee_team

```sql
SELECT task_numb,
owner_id,
title,
description,
progress
WHERE ds = 'DATEID'
AND progress != 'FINISHED'
```

I need to use the owner_id(int) to get employee_name(string) from another hive table. Does it make sense to join with the other table or use a subquery and display the result in the owner_id column? How would that be structured?

Example:

```sql
SELECT
task_numb,
(SELECT employee_name
FROM employee_info 
WHERE employee_id = owner_id) as Owner
title,
description,
progress
WHERE ds = '<today>'
AND progress != 'FINISHED'
```

Comment: yes that will work, although you should alias the tables and qualify the names to make it clear you mean `ei.employee_id = at.owner_id`.  there's not much actual difference between this and an inner join and depending on the query optimizer they might end up doing the exact same operations

Answer (score 0):

why not use simple join with emp tbale ?

```
SELECT
task_numb,
e.employee_name as Owner
title,
description,
progress
from Assigned_Tasks 
join employee_info e on  employee_id = owner_id  -- join emp table.
WHERE ds = '<today>'
AND progress != 'FINISHED'
```

if emp id is unique in employee_info table, there shouldnt be any issue.